# How to clean up profanity on airwaves

Tags: united-states, legal, repeater

We have a repeater here in Southern California (Sylmar K6GE 147.435), and no matter what time of day or night there are a great many operators spewing tremendous profanity, disrespect and meanness toward one another.  This is embarrassing and makes if very hard for parents to get their children into ham radio when the air is full of this nastiness.

Considering profanity is prohibited by FCC and there are supposed to be Auxiliary monitors helping police this type of thing, what can one do to find out if there are any actions being taken to track down and punish these nasty operators?

Comment: If memory serves correctly that is quite a notorious repeater. Many people have filed complaints over the years. I would chalk this repeater as a blight on the community and choose one of the other many repeaters in the area. (as a side note, whats the point of bringing up kids? People always try to stir up emotion by channeling "Wont somebody please think of the children?!" its an unneeded detail. We all want clean airwaves. it has nothing to do with kids.)

Answer (score 10):

I've heard --from reliable sources-- that about the only thing that can stop that is to make recordings that you can send to the FCC. Include well-thought-out documentation with callsigns, times and dates, frequencies, and any other relevant information.

The ARRL [may contact the FCC](http://www.arrl.org/amateur-auxiliary) for you.

Comment: I don't like profanity any more than you. When I hear it, I spin the VFO. :-)

Comment: Yes that works but that does not work well for my son's scanner. I also don't like changing my enjoyment of the hobby to a bunch of foul, mouthed, rule violating thugs.

Comment: @ChiliYago Can you lock out that channel?

Comment: Yes I can.  The point is it is illegal and should be investigated because it is so blatant.

Comment: @ChiliYago seems like you know the situation and now the legal aspects, as well as the right way to report. Mark this as answered? It's no use dwelling on any repeater's community here. Not productive.

Answer (score 0):

If you can lock it out then it should work well with your son's scanner. I've also noticed the same activity on 147. 45